# How to find out number of connected client to the server with their IP (detail) over TCP using a ServerSocket?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking, tcp

I have a server program is running on my PC. The server program using socket to connect to many clients. Is there anyway to find out which client with witch IP is connected to the server at any time? Or how many clients are connected to the server?

Comment: Which type of server do you have? Is it JEE, using a framework like netty or did you write your own ServerSocket handling code?

Comment: @PeterLawrey My own ServerSocket.

Comment: You need to define your terms here. If you want to count connections, just increment a counter when you accept one and decrement it when you close. If you want to count clients you need to define what identifies a client. Unless the client sends a UID of some kind all you have is the remote peer address, which might be the external address of a NAT device with hundreds of clients behind it, so it doesn't really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway to find out which client with witch IP is connected to the server at any time [using] My own ServerSocket.

When you accept a socket you can get its remote IP address.

```
Sockets socket = serverSocket.accept();
SocketAddress address = socket.getRemoteSocketAddress();
```

If there are multiple clients connecting from that IP, this is not enough to tell the difference.  If this is an issue you can have the client send a unique id so you know which client it is.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's the issue because I need to find out clients from the seam IP. Is there any to find out how many clients are connected to the ServerSocket?

Comment: clients are only connected to a Socket. If you want to know all the clients which are connected to the Sockets you accepts you need to keep them in a collection.

Comment: One "socket" equals one "connection" (or one "listener").  Note that a single client can open multiple connections.

Comment: Also note you can have multiple clients appear to come from the same IP address (but be different clients)